# How to break CORS policy for images in nextjs

Tags: next.js, cors, nextjs-image

In my nextjs project, I'm using `<Image />` component from next/image. I'm accessing images from a CDN hosted in digitalOcean server. For some reason CORS policy for the CDN isn't working properly, so images don't load in my browser (using Chrome). When I use default loader of nextjs, images works fine, coz I have seen that next/image works like request is sending from the same origin (https://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=imageUrl), so cors error doesn't occur. But default loader doesn't work with `next export`. So I had to use akamai loader instead of default loader. For using akamai loader, now images are being called directly using imgUrl (https://example.com/slider.jpg). I have tried multiple solutions but can't solve the problem.
CORS error -

```
Access to image at 'https://someCDNurl/promotion/ac-1.JPG' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

At last, I have tried to add custom response header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. But this header works for fetching resources from the pages I guess. But I don't know how to set headers for specific url like `https://example.com/` that gets fetched by the browser.
Can anyone tell me how to add a custom header for fetching resource from specific url or any other way/hack to solve this problem?
I'm using nextjs version 11. My `next.config.js` :

```
/* const withBundleAnalyzer = require('@next/bundle-analyzer')({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === 'true',
}) */


module.exports = ({
    async headers() {
    return [
      {
   
        source: '/(.*)',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
            value:
              '*',
          },
         
        ],
      },
    
    ]
  }, 
  
  devIndicators: {
    autoPrerender: false,
  },
  images: {
    domains: ['example1.com', 'example2.com'],
    loader: 'akamai', 
    path: '',
    disableStaticImages: false,
    minimumCacheTTL: 60,
    formats: ['image/webp'],
    
     
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  env: {
    PG_PUBLIC_KEY: process.env.PG_PUBLIC_KEY,
    PRIVATE_KEY : process.env.PRIVATE_KEY,
    MERCHANT_ID : process.env.MERCHANT_ID,
    NAGAD_BASE_URL : process.env.NAGAD_BASE_URL,
    MERCHANT_NUMBER : process.env.MERCHANT_NUMBER,
    MERCHANT_CALLBACK_URL: process.env.MERCHANT_CALLBACK_URL,
  },
  
 
});
```

My image component in the frontend:

```
                                      import Image from 'next/image';
                                      <Image
                                            unoptimized={true}
                                            //loader={myLoader}
                                            // src={item.imgUrl}
                                            crossOrigin="anonymous"
                                            src={getImgUrl(item.imgUrl)}
                                            height={200}

                                            width={410}
                                            layout="responsive"
                                            objectFit="cover"
                                           
                                            alt="banner"
                                        />
```

Comment: Why are the images loaded via XHR/fetch? this does not seem right

Comment: @MarianTheisen browser fetch the images from the CDN. it gets fetched by the browser.

Comment: and also try to add someCDNurl inside domains.because error says domain is not added.

Comment: _How_ are you loading that image in your frontend? Using an `img` element?

Comment: @jub0bs Inside <Image /> from next/image.

Comment: @Ishrat Do you actually need that `crossOrigin` attribute? Are you using the image in a `canvas` element or something? What happens if you remove the `crossOrigin` attribute?

Comment: @jub0bs I wasn't initially using crossOrigin attribute, just saw somewhere as a solution, so tried.

Comment: @Ishrat And adding or removing it yields the same CORS error message?

Comment: @jub0bs yes. same error.

Comment: @Ishrat Can you add a screenshot of the response from your browser's Network tab?

Comment: _"I'm accessing images from a CDN hosted in digitalOcean server"_ - Are your images hosted in Akamai? To use the Akamai loader your images need to be served from Akamai.

Comment: @juliomalves Not hsoted in the Akamai. I'm just using the akamai loader instead of default loader because default loader doesn't work with 'next export'

Comment: @Ishrat have you solved the problem?

Comment: @Rostyk Not yet. Still the problem exists.

Answer (score -2):

add domains parameter which image comes in next.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ["example.com"],
  },
};
```

Comment: already added. Doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Ishrat so use default img tag or find any lazy loading image component package.

Comment: default img tag also doesn't work.

Comment: I think it is something with your api please console.log the result .which type of image send in your response. it is a url or base64?

Comment: browser couldn't fetch the image. So there is no response actually. Browser says failed to fetch. 403 error code.

Comment: which api do you use?

Comment: sorry couldn't understand your question. I'm not calling any api for images. I am just trying to load imges from a CDN inside <Image /> component. The browser is doing the fetching task. not me.

Comment: ok, the CDN which you want to get image CORS is activated it could only be accessible only to the application which has origins that are specified in the server so you can not read that image.

Comment: yes but I need to access it somehow. In the CDN side, everything is set to '*' but still the problem remains. Seems like it's a bug in the CDN side. But I must find a way to access the images.